# Actualizar una app ya subida al play-store

Tags: android, android-studio, app, google-play

Tengo una app subida al *play-store* de *Google*, la cual he ido actualizando varias veces, sin problemas. Mientras iba creando la actualización a partir del código existente con el *Eclipse*, cada vez que probaba mi aplicación en mi móvil, esta borraba la anterior y se instalaba la nueva. Y cuando la subía al *play-store*, hacía lo mismo con todas las personas que tuviera instalada la app. hasta aquí todo bien.

El problema viene ahora:

Recientemente he instalado el *Adroid Studio*, para crear una actualización de mi app, pero esta vez quiero reescribir todo el código desde cero. Y me he dado cuenta que cada vez que pruebo la aplicación mientras voy creándola, esta se instala correctamente, pero no me borra la que está instalada que ya me había bajado del *play-store*. Con lo cual no sustituye a la anterior aplicación sino que deja las dos aplicaciones instaladas.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi aplicación que vuelto a crear de cero con pequeñas modificaciones sustituya a la anterior?

Comment: Mira a ver si se llaman igual o si el nombre del paquete en el que se encuentra la app coincide.

Comment: ¿las dos aplicaciones tienen el mismo paquete o uno diferente? me refiero al `package=cam.x.a` del maniffest o al  ` applicationId` del build.gradle

Comment: @Natlum, Natlum en Android Studio también se configura en el archivo build.gradle, cuya configuración sobreescribe la del AndroidManifest.xml revisa si ahí lo tienes definido, ve mi respuesta.

Comment: @Natlum Disculpa como se le hace para actualizar una app que ya esta en la play store?

Comment: Muy buenas, para empezar tienes que ir al apartado de versiones de la App y crear una nueva versión, te pedirá que subas el apk que has tenido que generar anteriormente con el Android Studio y firmado con la misma Key que se firmó la versión que está subida, luego rellenas el formulario y le das a publicar. La versión antigua se guarda automáticamente en el baúl de artefactos y se puede volver a publicar si la actualización da problemas. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Para desinstalar apps, datos etc... yo uso un plugin para adndroid stduio el ADB idea

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Si, esto está perfectamente en línea con el proceso de actualización de la aplicación de Google Play.

Google-play determina que una solicitud es una actualización basada en dos criterios:

1 - El nombre del paquete de la aplicación.

2 - Tu código de la versión

Para ser considerado como una actualización, tu nueva aplicación debe tener exactamente el mismo nombre que el paquete anterior ("com.example.myapp"), y su `android:versionCode` tiene que ser mayor, en su archivo AndroidManifest.xml. Por supuesto, el APK debe ser firmado con la clave privada de su cuenta, al igual que cualquier aplicación publicada bajo su cuenta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la rapidez en contestar. Al parecer tengo mal puesto el nombre del paquete de la aplicación y el id. He intentado modificarlo pero no veo cómo hacerlo. Tengo android studio 2.2 y se supone que con el botón derecho sobre la raiz de la aplicación tiene que aparecer open module settings. Para poder cambiarlo.

Comment: Quizás te ayuda ésta respuesta: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698/6124910

Comment: Muchas gracias Patrick y a Error404, Joacer, Elenasys. He seguido los pasos y ha funcionado correctamente. Ahora ya me sustituye la aplicación por la nueva. Pero me ha salido una duda y es que al instalarla en mi móvil me ha dado un error el Android Studio. El error es el siguiente: Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

Comment: Si le doy a ok me hace lo que yo quiero, pero mi pregunta es si esto le pasarán a todos los usuarios que la actualice o sólo a mi porque la estoy actualizando desde el IDE

Answer (score 9):

> Si creas una nueva aplicación y al instalarla desde la PlayStore no
>   sustituye la anterior.

**El problema es que definiste tu aplicación con otro identificador único, en pocas palabras con otro nombre de paquete diferente.**

**Una actualización de aplicación debe ser creada con el mismo paquete de aplicación y firmada con el mismo Keystore.**

El paquete de aplicación en el caso de Android Studio puede definirse también en el archivo `build.gradle` además del `AndroidManifest.xml`, es importante saber que la configuración definida en el `build.gradle` sobreescribe a la del `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Para cambiar la configuración de tu nombre de paquete, no necesitas entrar en `module settings`, simplemente realizalo en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` o tu `build.gradle`, obviamente los directorios cambiarian de nombre, lo cual tienes que realizar refactorizando o cambiando manualmente.

Ejemplo configuración `build.gradle` :

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.mydomain.myapp"
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
     ...
  }

}
```

Ejemplo configuración `AndroidManifest.xml` (Puedes usar también un archivo .json) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mydomain.myapp"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" >
```

El `versionCode` no influye en que se instale otra aplicación diferente, solo debes cuidar tenga un valor entero consecutivo cada nueva versión.

---

Desgraciadamente no se podrá instalar una actualización de la aplicación ya que el paquete es único y solo puede actualizar la aplicación que tenga el mismo paquete, de hecho el url de instalación de una aplicación esta definido por el paquete como id:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mydominio.myapplicacion

Comment: Muy buena explicación muchas gracias

Comment: @Natlum con respecto al error: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE. actualic´+e mi respuesta "Desgraciadamente no se podrá instalar una actualización de la aplicación ya que el paquete es único y solo puede actualizar la aplicación que tenga el mismo paquete"

Comment: Bueno compañeros, para salir de dudas he exportado el apk y lo he subido al Google play, en el apartado de Alpha Testing. Lo primero que me encontré es que si o si, hay que poner la key original del la primera app, sino el Google Play no lo reconoce como una actualización. Una vez creada con la key correcta, me ha dejado subirla y aparece en el estado de en alpha. Ahora sólo tengo que esperar a que me llegue sólo a mi la actualización. Espero que mis problemas les sirvan de solución para otros usuarios como yo. Ya iré contando cómo ha terminado mi problema. Un saludo y muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: La aplicación con el mismo id debe de ser firmada con el mismo Keystore de "producción" (Por favor, no lo pierdas!) si la pudiste subir como nueva aplicación es porque tiene el mismo nombre de paquete. Saludos y suerte @Natlum

Comment: Perfecto, todo salió perfecto. Hoy se me descargó la aplicación que puse en alpha dentro del Google play y reemplazó la que me había instalado anteriormente sin ningún problema. Vuelvo a dar las gracias a todos por esta gran ayuda.

Comment: Perfecto Natlum! Ahora a producción! :)