# Notificar al usuario de actualizacion disponible en Google Play en aplicación android

Tags: android, google-play

¿Cómo hago para que mi aplicación **detecte** que ya subí a la google play store una nueva versión y que **notifique** que ya se encuentra una nueva actualización disponible?

Mi app trabaja con un Web Api y pensaba realizar cambios "grandes" tanto en el Web api como en mi app, y a la hora de publicar mi Web Api cuando termine esos cambios va a generar problemas con las personas que NO actualicen la app, entonces pensaba hacer que mi app detecte que se subió una nueva versión a la Play Store y notifique (prácticamente obligue al usuario) para que la actualicen.

Comment: Hola @lois6b la pregunta no es duplicada de ninguna, en aquellas preguntaban por el proceso bruto para actualizar, Mientras Steven quiere que cuando haga ese proceso desde su app se dectecte y le avise al usuario

Comment: @jasilva, tienes razon. El titulo es un poco confuso pues. deberia ser algo asi como "Notificar al usuario de actualizacion disponible"

Comment: Mi duda es: quieres que la propia app lo notifique? ya que Play Store tiene sus propias notificaciones de Actualizaciones disponibles

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Actualizar una app ya subida al play-store](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29880/actualizar-una-app-ya-subida-al-play-store)

Comment: Steven, toda la informacion ha de estar en la pregunta, no en los comentarios

Answer (score 2):

Te explicaré mi modo de hacerlo en mi app, no se si es la más optima pero a mi me sirve.

Mediante mi WebAPI, tengo una función que retorna las versiones que se pueden ejecutar actualmente y las que se pueden ejecutar pero que necesitan actualizar, por ejemplo:

Al iniciar la app, antes del login consulto que versiones estan aceptadas, esto me devuelve que la version actual es la V1.5 y las soportadas son las V1.3 y V1.4.

- Si la versión que estoy ejecutando es la V1.5, no muestro nada, o si quiero muestro algún mensaje informativo no asociado a alguna actualización.
- Si la versión que estoy ejecutando es la V1.4 o la V1.3 le saldría una dialog con el texto que tambien lo devuelve la consulta: "Esta versión dejará de funcionar el DD/MM/AAAA
  por favor actualizar en la Playstore" con dos botones, Ir a la
  playstore y Omitir.
- Si la versión es la V1.2 o menor, muestro un dialog con el
  `.setCancelable(false);` "Esta versión es obsoleta, por favor
  actualizar en la Playstore" y dos botones, "Ir a la Playstore" y
  "Salir", el cual este ultimo, finalizaría la aplicación, todo esto
  para impedir que el usuario pueda seguir usando esta version.

Un último consejo, éste método a consultar debes hacerlo independiente a otros procesos que puedan ser modificados en el futuro y trata de hacerlo lo más ajustado y completo a tus necesidades para que la modificación en el futuro sea mínima, por mi parte tengo una tabla con un solo registro en la base de datos con los campos, versionActual, versionesAceptadas, mensajeVersionActual, mensajeVersionesAceptadas, mensajeVersionesObsoletas y otras extras.

Comment: Tendras algun de como realizarlo

Comment: Hola @HugoRodriguez La ultima vez que implementé esto fue con Firebase, que posee una herramienta bastante amigable llamada Remote Config, que te permite crear variables en el servidor y solicitarlas en cualquier momento que la necesites en tu aplicación. En mi caso, la solicito al inicio y la comparo con la versión del apk. Mas informacion : [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/products/remote-config/?hl=es-419)