# ¿Cómo notificar al usuario cuando hay una nueva versión en mi aplicación?

Tags: android

Actualmente estoy presentando un problema en mi aplicación realizada en Android Studio, resulta que cuando subo una nueva actualización esta no se ve reflejada con los usuarios que la tienen instalada, he hecho pruebas como usuario y el numero de versión si se actualiza pero los cambios no, a pesar de que las actualizaciones automáticas están habilitadas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siempre debo dar en el botón actualizar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que el usuario al menos sea notificado de que hay una actualización y que debe actualizar la app para seguirla utilizando, por lo tanto lo único que se me ocurrió es hacer lo que hacen muchas aplicaciones y es crear un cuadro de dialogo como el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y asi el usuario sea redireccionado a la tienda para que pueda realizar la actualización y que mientras en versionCode o el versionName sean diferentes a la version que esta en la google play no deje de mostrar el cuadro de dialogo.

Como ultimo punto investigando un poco al respecto me di cuenta que este problema que tengo no se me debería de presentar ya que eso lo hace Google Play sin embargo en mi caso no es asi, no se si mi problema en en Android Studio o en la Google Play Console (Mi aplicacion es una beta abierta).

Ya he consultado varios sitios al respecto y un par de preguntas en StackOverFlow

> https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/46139/114296

> https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/165113/114296

De antemano muchas gracias, espero me puedan orientar.

Comment: esto te puede servir https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo, voy a revisar e intentar aplicarlo a mi app y luego te cuento como me fue, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré una solucion siguiendo la guia que nos dejo Sinner!
Creando el siguiente código en la clase donde quieren que se muestre el dialogo

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    checkNewAppVersionState();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, final int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    switch (requestCode) {

        case REQ_CODE_VERSION_UPDATE:
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) { //RESULT_OK / RESULT_CANCELED / RESULT_IN_APP_UPDATE_FAILED
                log("Update flow failed! Result code: " + resultCode);
                // If the update is cancelled or fails,
                // you can request to start the update again.
                unregisterInstallStateUpdListener();
            }

            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterInstallStateUpdListener();
    super.onDestroy();
}


private void checkForAppUpdate() {
    // Creates instance of the manager.
    appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);

    // Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
    Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();

    // Create a listener to track request state updates.
    installStateUpdatedListener = new InstallStateUpdatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStateUpdate(InstallState installState) {
            // Show module progress, log state, or install the update.
            if (installState.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED)
                // After the update is downloaded, show a notification
                // and request user confirmation to restart the app.
                popupSnackbarForCompleteUpdateAndUnregister();
        }
    };

    // Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
        if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE) {
            // Request the update.
            if (appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)) {

                // Before starting an update, register a listener for updates.
                appUpdateManager.registerListener(installStateUpdatedListener);
                // Start an update.
                startAppUpdateFlexible(appUpdateInfo);
            } else if (appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE) ) {
                // Start an update.
                startAppUpdateImmediate(appUpdateInfo);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void startAppUpdateImmediate(AppUpdateInfo appUpdateInfo) {
    try {
        appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                appUpdateInfo,
                AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                // The current activity making the update request.
                this,
                // Include a request code to later monitor this update request.
                Login.REQ_CODE_VERSION_UPDATE);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void startAppUpdateFlexible(AppUpdateInfo appUpdateInfo) {
    try {
        appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                appUpdateInfo,
                AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE,
                // The current activity making the update request.
                this,
                // Include a request code to later monitor this update request.
                Login.REQ_CODE_VERSION_UPDATE);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        unregisterInstallStateUpdListener();
    }
}

/**
 * Displays the snackbar notification and call to action.
 * Needed only for Flexible app update
 */
private void popupSnackbarForCompleteUpdateAndUnregister() {


    Snackbar snackbar =
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.light), getString(R.string.update_downloaded), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    snackbar.setAction(R.string.restart, new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            appUpdateManager.completeUpdate();
        }
    });
    snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.rosado));
    snackbar.show();

    unregisterInstallStateUpdListener();
}

/**
 * Checks that the update is not stalled during 'onResume()'.
 * However, you should execute this check at all app entry points.
 */
private void checkNewAppVersionState() {
    appUpdateManager
            .getAppUpdateInfo()
            .addOnSuccessListener(
                    appUpdateInfo -> {
                        //FLEXIBLE:
                        // If the update is downloaded but not installed,
                        // notify the user to complete the update.
                        if (appUpdateInfo.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED) {
                            popupSnackbarForCompleteUpdateAndUnregister();
                        }

                        //IMMEDIATE:
                        if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability()
                                == UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS) {
                            // If an in-app update is already running, resume the update.
                            startAppUpdateImmediate(appUpdateInfo);
                        }
                    });

}

/**
 * Needed only for FLEXIBLE update
 */
private void unregisterInstallStateUpdListener() {
    if (appUpdateManager != null && installStateUpdatedListener != null)
        appUpdateManager.unregisterListener(installStateUpdatedListener);
}
```

y obteniendo el metodo en el onCreate

checkForAppUpdate();

Asi casa vez que el usuario inicie la aplicacion esta validara si la version que se esta ejecutando es la misma que esta subida a la play store, espero que a alguien le sirva en el futuro.