# Forzar la actualización de aplicación en Play Store

Tags: android, phonegap, google-play, google-play-console

Tengo un problema, el caso es que tengo que subir una aplicación al `Play Store` desarrollada con `Phonegap`, y cada vez que realice una actualización lo que quiero es que la app no funcione a menos que la actualicen.

No he encontrado forma de hacerlo mediante código (en el `config.xml`o lo que sea), lo que si que he escuchado es que se puede hacer mediante el `Play Store` (configurándolo al subir la app), ¿es cierto esto?

Saludos.

Comment: No, eso no es posible. La única forma es que su aplicación verifique un servicio web externo al iniciarse, y si el servicio dice que hay una versión más nueva, la aplicación debe cerrar y redireccionar al usuario a Play Store para recibir actualizaciones.

Comment: ¿Qué significa verificar un servicio web? Que la app esté alojada en un sitio que no sea Play Store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hasta el día de hoy (septiembre 2018) esto no es posible desde la [consola Google Play](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/).**

Actualmente, la única forma que se realice la actualización es cuando el usuario lo permite:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El bloquear la aplicación y provocar la deban actualizar para que continué funcionando lo debes realizar en la misma. Por ejemplo obtener la versión de tu aplicación y compararla con un archivo .xml, .json o la respuesta de un web service que tenga la versión actual a actualizar, si la versión de la aplicación es menor puedes mostrar un dialogo para:

- Mostrar un mensaje de aviso y continuar usando tu aplicación en caso de no aceptar la actualización.
- Mostrar un mensaje de aviso y NO permitir continuar usando tu aplicación en caso de no aceptar la actualización.

Este es un método que realicé para leer directamente desde la página [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store) la actual versión de tu aplicación en la tienda para ser comparada con la de tu .apk instalado:

**[Actualizar una app ya subida al play-store](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/29892/95)**

---

Otros métodos pueden ser hacer uso de alguna librería como:

- [AndroidSmartUpdates](https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidSmartUpdates). Biblioteca anterior, pero con instrucciones
  en inglés y también proporciona una secuencia de comandos del
  servidor.
- [AppUpdateChecker](https://github.com/mitmel/AppUpdateChecker) Una forma simple que no es de Market para
  mantener su aplicación actualizada. Todo lo que necesita para
  configurar es una URL que apunta a un documento JSON que describe los
  cambios de su aplicación.
- [android auto updater client](https://github.com/NDMAC/android-auto-updater-client) Este proyecto permite actualizar
  automáticamente una aplicación .APK en ejecución usando un servidor de
  actualización privado (ver apk-updater) en lugar del actualizador de
  Google Play. También viene con una secuencia de comandos del
  servidor. SmartUpdates. Biblioteca anterior, pero con instrucciones
  en inglés y también proporciona una secuencia de comandos del
  servidor.

---

**Actualización:**

Para dispositivos con sistema operativo 5.0 o posterior se puede usar como opción
**[In-app updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates)**

> Mantener su aplicación actualizada en los dispositivos de sus usuarios
>   les permite probar nuevas funciones, así como beneficiarse de mejoras
>   de rendimiento y correcciones de errores. Aunque algunos usuarios
>   habilitan actualizaciones en segundo plano cuando su dispositivo está
>   conectado a una conexión no medida, otros usuarios pueden necesitar
>   que se les recuerde que deben actualizar. Las actualizaciones en la
>   aplicación son una función de la biblioteca de Play Core que introduce
>   un nuevo flujo de solicitudes para solicitar a los usuarios activos
>   que actualicen su aplicación.

Answer (score 2):

No, eso no es posible. La única forma es que su aplicación verifique un servicio externo al iniciarse, y si el servicio dice que hay una versión más nueva, la aplicación debe cerrar y redireccionar al usuario a Play Store para recibir actualizaciones.

La mayoría de las aplicaciones dependen de un servidor externo ([CMS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_gesti%C3%B3n_de_contenidos)) para los datos; probablemente puedas usarlo para crear dicho servicio. De lo contrario, basta con alojar un archivo simple que contenga el último número de versión.