# Obligar actualizar app a los usuarios

Tags: android, ionic, ios, app, google-play

Estoy haciendo cambios en una aplicación que ya está subida tanto a play store como a apple store, mi pregunta es la siguiente:

-Como puedo hacer para que cuando suba mi app actualizada, obligue a los usuarios a actualizarla.

Un saludo, gracias.

Comment: Aunque sea vieja la pregunta mira a ver si te sirve de algo [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244305/force-update-of-an-android-app-when-a-new-version-is-available) . Un Saludo

Comment: Google desde api 21 tiene una api para eso, no puede usar la app hasta q actualiza, tambien tiene la opcion de actualizar en background

Answer (score 1):

En iOS hay una librería llamada **Siren**, te dejo el link:
[Siren GitHub](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren)

Debes agregar el pod:

```
pod 'Siren'
```

En el AppDelegate importas la librería

```
import Siren
```

En la función del AppDelegate **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** llamas a la librería

```
Siren.shared.wail()
```

En el link hay más detalles de cómo quieres que se presente al usuario si existe una versión de tu App.

Answer (score 0):

**No existe una forma nativa de obligar a los usuarios a actualizar**, ya que el usuario es el que debe permitir la actualización, a menos que tenga seleccionada la opción auto-update.

Revisa para Android la pregunta, en la cual se agregan opciones para "provocar" la actualización :

**[Forzar la actualización de aplicación en Play Store](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/199271/forzar-la-actualizaci%c3%b3n-de-aplicaci%c3%b3n-en-play-store/199651#199651)**

**Lo principal para que las aplicaciones instaladas a los usuarios detecten una actualización es que definas en tu app un `versionCode` mayor al definido en la versión que se encuentra actualmente en Google Play Store.**

Como ejemplo, si tu última versión de la aplicación tiene un Version Code 16

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Define dentro de tu build.gradle una versión mayor, en este caso sería la 17:

```
 android {
      ...
      defaultConfig {
        ...
        versionCode 17
        versionName "1.6"
      }
    }
```

Revisa:

[Cómo establecer la versión de tu app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning?hl=es-419)

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo una app que obliga a realizar la actualización, pero obviamente no es nativa y requiere además una API. Lo que hago es:

Primero, obtener el valor de la versión actual de la app (ejemplo 6.1):

```
PackageInfo pInfo;
pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
version = pInfo.versionName;
```

Luego, obtengo el valor de la versión que debería ser des de la API, por ejemplo 6.2. Si no coincide, sale un diálogo que notifica la necesidad de actualizar. Un botón ofrece camino directo a Google Play, y el otro, ofrece la opción de no actualizar. Esta última opción no deja continuar con la app realizando un `finish()` hacia el login o un `exit`.

No olvides de subir el valor de `versionCode` cada vez que cambies de versión.