# ¿Cómo controlar que la aplicación esté siempre actualizada?

Tags: android, android-studio, update, google-play-games

tengo esta duda
Lo que pasa es que voy a publicar un juego, este juego tiene un ranking de google que BORRARÉ CADA SEMANA, vi que no puedo eliminar los datos de mi ranking de google, entonces cada semana tendré que crear de nuevo el ranking y publicar una actualización cada semana.

Lo que quiero saber es como puedo controlar que los jugadores siempre tengan el juego actualizadao ?

Es decir, que no puedan entrar a cierta ventana, a menos que el juego esté en su última versión en la PlayStore.

GRACIAS POR SU AYUDA!

Comment: puedes hacerlo validando la version que tienes en el playstore haciendo una solicitud a:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp&hl=es  donde com.whatsapp seria el nombre del paquete
buscas la clase `htlgb` su text seria la `ultima fecha de actualizacion`
comparas y listo!

Comment: Hola, podría ponerme en contacto contigo de alguna forma ?
Cuando dices hacer una solicitud a ese sitio web, a qué te refieres ? 

POR FAVOR, me gustaría mucho poder hablar contigo más fluido

Comment: En realidad solo puedes sugerir a los usuarios que actualicen su aplicación, revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/199271/forzar-la-actualizaci%C3%B3n-de-aplicaci%C3%B3n-en-play-store/199651#199651 y https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/29892/95 que es parecido a lo que comenta Bryro. Pero creo que la mejor forma de realizar lo que desees es que los datos del Rankng sean leidos de una fuente externa como un Webservice o un archivo ,json